# How to delete everything after the cursor?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7, how can I delete a huge mass of text and pictures after my cursor in Notepad, MS Word, MS Outlook etc... efficiently? Also, some minimal programs like Notepad lack an explicit function to delete after the cursor. Assume that the text and pictures are overly lengthy for 
Methods 1 & 3:

> **Method 1:** 1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to select line of text (hou can hold <kbd>Down</kbd> to select many)
>
> 2. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>
>
> **Method 3:** *[Edit: It's overly unproductive and wasteful to highlight everything after the cursor]*
>
> 1. Select and copy text you need.
> 2. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and delete everything.
> 3. Paste previously copied text.

**Afterword:** Despite the array of choices in user Kamil's answer below, I desired only **Method 2.1:**

> 1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (select all text after cursor in current line) or
>
>    Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (select all
>      text after cursor in whole text)

Comment: I usually use key commands to handle stuff like this. Shift + End highlights everything on the line after the cursor, Shift + Down arror or Page Down will highlight full lines below the partial line you already selected, etc. This avoids all the clumbsiness of MS trying to predict where your highlight will end, and almost always making the wrong choice about it, especially on long lines without wordwrap, where the page must scroll as you are selecting. Visual Studio is a real pain in this regard.

Comment: Copy only needed data into a new file?

Comment: @LittleHelper Alas, it's also inefficient to copy the needed data that's too long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1:**

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> to select line of text (hou can hold <kbd>Down</kbd> to select many)
2. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

**Method 2:**

1. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (select all text after cursor in current line) or

   Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>End</kbd> (select all text after cursor in whole text)
2. Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd>

**Method 3:**

1. Select and copy text you need.
2. Select all (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) and delete everything.
3. Paste previously copied text.

---

These shortcuts should work in any program.

---

More universal shortcuts:

[42+ Text-Editing Keyboard Shortcuts That Work Almost Everywhere (at howtogeek.com)](http://www.howtogeek.com/115664/42-text-editing-keyboard-shortcuts-that-work-almost-everywhere/)

Comment: Thanks. Did you intend to list Press <kbd>Delete</kbd> or <kbd>Backspace</kbd> twice?

Comment: Also, your Method 2.1 was exactly what I sought! To wit, I was seeking the trick `Shift + End`.